# Tracing x86 in gdb to find passcode

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, reverse-engineering

I have been given an executable that asks for a passcode input.  The only way to find the hidden passcode is to use gdb and trace x86.  I have tried setting breakpoints at different points and looking in values of registers but I cannot figure out how to find the password.  This is also hard because there is no main method. The attached x86 is very long but I feel like a lot of it is unnecessary. Any help would be appreciated.  I just don't know where to start.  Thanks.

```
Disassembly of section .init:

080482f8 <.init>:
 80482f8:       55                      push   %ebp
 80482f9:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80482fb:       53                      push   %ebx
 80482fc:       83 ec 04                sub    $0x4,%esp
 80482ff:       e8 00 00 00 00          call   8048304 <getchar@plt-0x34>
 8048304:       5b                      pop    %ebx
 8048305:       81 c3 b0 14 00 00       add    $0x14b0,%ebx
 804830b:       8b 93 fc ff ff ff       mov    -0x4(%ebx),%edx
 8048311:       85 d2                   test   %edx,%edx
 8048313:       74 05                   je     804831a <getchar@plt-0x1e>
 8048315:       e8 2e 00 00 00          call   8048348 <__gmon_start__@plt>
 804831a:       e8 11 01 00 00          call   8048430 <tolower@plt+0xa8>
 804831f:       e8 6c 02 00 00          call   8048590 <tolower@plt+0x208>
 8048324:       58                      pop    %eax
 8048325:       5b                      pop    %ebx
 8048326:       c9                      leave
 8048327:       c3                      ret

Disassembly of section .plt:

08048328 <getchar@plt-0x10>:
 8048328:       ff 35 b8 97 04 08       pushl  0x80497b8
 804832e:       ff 25 bc 97 04 08       jmp    *0x80497bc
 8048334:       00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
        ...

08048338 <getchar@plt>:
 8048338:       ff 25 c0 97 04 08       jmp    *0x80497c0
 804833e:       68 00 00 00 00          push   $0x0
 8048343:       e9 e0 ff ff ff          jmp    8048328 <getchar@plt-0x10>

08048348 <__gmon_start__@plt>:
 8048348:       ff 25 c4 97 04 08       jmp    *0x80497c4
 804834e:       68 08 00 00 00          push   $0x8
 8048353:       e9 d0 ff ff ff          jmp    8048328 <getchar@plt-0x10>

08048358 <__libc_start_main@plt>:
 8048358:       ff 25 c8 97 04 08       jmp    *0x80497c8
 804835e:       68 10 00 00 00          push   $0x10
 8048363:       e9 c0 ff ff ff          jmp    8048328 <getchar@plt-0x10>

08048368 <printf@plt>:
 8048368:       ff 25 cc 97 04 08       jmp    *0x80497cc
 804836e:       68 18 00 00 00          push   $0x18
 8048373:       e9 b0 ff ff ff          jmp    8048328 <getchar@plt-0x10>

08048378 <puts@plt>:
 8048378:       ff 25 d0 97 04 08       jmp    *0x80497d0
 804837e:       68 20 00 00 00          push   $0x20
 8048383:       e9 a0 ff ff ff          jmp    8048328 <getchar@plt-0x10>

08048388 <tolower@plt>:
 8048388:       ff 25 d4 97 04 08       jmp    *0x80497d4
 804838e:       68 28 00 00 00          push   $0x28
 8048393:       e9 90 ff ff ff          jmp    8048328 <getchar@plt-0x10>

Disassembly of section .text:

080483a0 <.text>:
 80483a0:       31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
 80483a2:       5e                      pop    %esi
 80483a3:       89 e1                   mov    %esp,%ecx
 80483a5:       83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 80483a8:       50                      push   %eax
 80483a9:       54                      push   %esp
 80483aa:       52                      push   %edx
 80483ab:       68 20 85 04 08          push   $0x8048520
 80483b0:       68 30 85 04 08          push   $0x8048530
 80483b5:       51                      push   %ecx
 80483b6:       56                      push   %esi
 80483b7:       68 0e 85 04 08          push   $0x804850e
 80483bc:       e8 97 ff ff ff          call   8048358 <__libc_start_main@plt>
 80483c1:       f4                      hlt
 80483c2:       90                      nop
 80483c3:       90                      nop
 80483c4:       90                      nop
 80483c5:       90                      nop
 80483c6:       90                      nop
 80483c7:       90                      nop
 80483c8:       90                      nop
 80483c9:       90                      nop
 80483ca:       90                      nop
 80483cb:       90                      nop
 80483cc:       90                      nop
 80483cd:       90                      nop
 80483ce:       90                      nop
 80483cf:       90                      nop
 80483d0:       55                      push   %ebp
 80483d1:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80483d3:       53                      push   %ebx
 80483d4:       83 ec 04                sub    $0x4,%esp
 80483d7:       80 3d dc 97 04 08 00    cmpb   $0x0,0x80497dc
 80483de:       75 3f                   jne    804841f <tolower@plt+0x97>
 80483e0:       a1 e0 97 04 08          mov    0x80497e0,%eax
 80483e5:       bb e0 96 04 08          mov    $0x80496e0,%ebx
 80483ea:       81 eb dc 96 04 08       sub    $0x80496dc,%ebx
 80483f0:       c1 fb 02                sar    $0x2,%ebx
 80483f3:       83 eb 01                sub    $0x1,%ebx
 80483f6:       39 d8                   cmp    %ebx,%eax
 80483f8:       73 1e                   jae    8048418 <tolower@plt+0x90>
 80483fa:       8d b6 00 00 00 00       lea    0x0(%esi),%esi
 8048400:       83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
 8048403:       a3 e0 97 04 08          mov    %eax,0x80497e0
 8048408:       ff 14 85 dc 96 04 08    call   *0x80496dc(,%eax,4)
 804840f:       a1 e0 97 04 08          mov    0x80497e0,%eax
 8048414:       39 d8                   cmp    %ebx,%eax
 8048416:       72 e8                   jb     8048400 <tolower@plt+0x78>
 8048418:       c6 05 dc 97 04 08 01    movb   $0x1,0x80497dc
 804841f:       83 c4 04                add    $0x4,%esp
 8048422:       5b                      pop    %ebx
 8048423:       5d                      pop    %ebp
 8048424:       c3                      ret
 8048425:       8d 74 26 00             lea    0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi
 8048429:       8d bc 27 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%edi,%eiz,1),%edi
 8048430:       55                      push   %ebp
 8048431:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048433:       83 ec 18                sub    $0x18,%esp
 8048436:       a1 e4 96 04 08          mov    0x80496e4,%eax
 804843b:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
 804843d:       74 12                   je     8048451 <tolower@plt+0xc9>
 804843f:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048444:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
 8048446:       74 09                   je     8048451 <tolower@plt+0xc9>
 8048448:       c7 04 24 e4 96 04 08    movl   $0x80496e4,(%esp)
 804844f:       ff d0                   call   *%eax
 8048451:       c9                      leave
 8048452:       c3                      ret
 8048453:       90                      nop
 8048454:       55                      push   %ebp
 8048455:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048457:       53                      push   %ebx
 8048458:       83 ec 34                sub    $0x34,%esp
 804845b:       c7 45 f0 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x10(%ebp)
 8048462:       c7 45 f4 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0xc(%ebp)
 8048469:       eb 10                   jmp    804847b <tolower@plt+0xf3>
 804846b:       8b 5d f4                mov    -0xc(%ebp),%ebx
 804846e:       e8 c5 fe ff ff          call   8048338 <getchar@plt>
 8048473:       88 44 1d e5             mov    %al,-0x1b(%ebp,%ebx,1)
 8048477:       83 45 f4 01             addl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)
 804847b:       83 7d f4 09             cmpl   $0x9,-0xc(%ebp)
 804847f:       7e ea                   jle    804846b <tolower@plt+0xe3>
 8048481:       8b 45 f4                mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
 8048484:       c6 44 05 e5 00          movb   $0x0,-0x1b(%ebp,%eax,1)
 8048489:       c7 45 f4 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)
 8048490:       eb 27                   jmp    80484b9 <tolower@plt+0x131>
 8048492:       8b 45 f4                mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
 8048495:       83 e8 01                sub    $0x1,%eax
 8048498:       0f b6 44 05 e5          movzbl -0x1b(%ebp,%eax,1),%eax
 804849d:       0f be c0                movsbl %al,%eax
 80484a0:       89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 80484a3:       e8 e0 fe ff ff          call   8048388 <tolower@plt>
 80484a8:       83 e8 31                sub    $0x31,%eax
 80484ab:       83 f8 04                cmp    $0x4,%eax
 80484ae:       77 05                   ja     80484b5 <tolower@plt+0x12d>
 80484b0:       83 45 f0 01             addl   $0x1,-0x10(%ebp)
 80484b4:       90                      nop
 80484b5:       83 45 f4 01             addl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)
 80484b9:       83 7d f4 0a             cmpl   $0xa,-0xc(%ebp)
 80484bd:       7e d3                   jle    8048492 <tolower@plt+0x10a>
 80484bf:       83 7d f0 0a             cmpl   $0xa,-0x10(%ebp)
 80484c3:       75 16                   jne    80484db <tolower@plt+0x153>
 80484c5:       b8 e4 85 04 08          mov    $0x80485e4,%eax
 80484ca:       8d 55 e5                lea    -0x1b(%ebp),%edx
 80484cd:       89 54 24 04             mov    %edx,0x4(%esp)
 80484d1:       89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 80484d4:       e8 8f fe ff ff          call   8048368 <printf@plt>
 80484d9:       eb 0c                   jmp    80484e7 <tolower@plt+0x15f>
 80484db:       c7 04 24 12 86 04 08    movl   $0x8048612,(%esp)
 80484e2:       e8 91 fe ff ff          call   8048378 <puts@plt>
 80484e7:       83 c4 34                add    $0x34,%esp
 80484ea:       5b                      pop    %ebx
 80484eb:       5d                      pop    %ebp
 80484ec:       c3                      ret
 80484ed:       55                      push   %ebp
 80484ee:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80484f0:       83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
 80484f3:       e8 5c ff ff ff          call   8048454 <tolower@plt+0xcc>
 80484f8:       c9                      leave
 80484f9:       c3                      ret
 80484fa:       55                      push   %ebp
 80484fb:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80484fd:       83 ec 18                sub    $0x18,%esp
 8048500:       c7 45 f4 26 86 04 08    movl   $0x8048626,-0xc(%ebp)
 8048507:       e8 e1 ff ff ff          call   80484ed <tolower@plt+0x165>
 804850c:       c9                      leave
 804850d:       c3                      ret
 804850e:       55                      push   %ebp
 804850f:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048511:       83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 8048514:       e8 e1 ff ff ff          call   80484fa <tolower@plt+0x172>
 8048519:       89 ec                   mov    %ebp,%esp
 804851b:       5d                      pop    %ebp
 804851c:       c3                      ret
 804851d:       90                      nop
 804851e:       90                      nop
 804851f:       90                      nop
 8048520:       55                      push   %ebp
 8048521:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048523:       5d                      pop    %ebp
 8048524:       c3                      ret
 8048525:       66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00    data32 nopw %cs:0x0(%eax,%eax,1)
 804852c:       00 00 00 00
 8048530:       55                      push   %ebp
 8048531:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048533:       57                      push   %edi
 8048534:       56                      push   %esi
 8048535:       53                      push   %ebx
 8048536:       e8 4f 00 00 00          call   804858a <tolower@plt+0x202>
 804853b:       81 c3 79 12 00 00       add    $0x1279,%ebx
 8048541:       83 ec 1c                sub    $0x1c,%esp
 8048544:       e8 af fd ff ff          call   80482f8 <getchar@plt-0x40>
 8048549:       8d bb 20 ff ff ff       lea    -0xe0(%ebx),%edi
 804854f:       8d 83 20 ff ff ff       lea    -0xe0(%ebx),%eax
 8048555:       29 c7                   sub    %eax,%edi
 8048557:       c1 ff 02                sar    $0x2,%edi
 804855a:       85 ff                   test   %edi,%edi
 804855c:       74 24                   je     8048582 <tolower@plt+0x1fa>
 804855e:       31 f6                   xor    %esi,%esi
 8048560:       8b 45 10                mov    0x10(%ebp),%eax
 8048563:       89 44 24 08             mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
 8048567:       8b 45 0c                mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
 804856a:       89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
 804856e:       8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
 8048571:       89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 8048574:       ff 94 b3 20 ff ff ff    call   *-0xe0(%ebx,%esi,4)
 804857b:       83 c6 01                add    $0x1,%esi
 804857e:       39 fe                   cmp    %edi,%esi
 8048580:       72 de                   jb     8048560 <tolower@plt+0x1d8>
 8048582:       83 c4 1c                add    $0x1c,%esp
 8048585:       5b                      pop    %ebx
 8048586:       5e                      pop    %esi
 8048587:       5f                      pop    %edi
 8048588:       5d                      pop    %ebp
 8048589:       c3                      ret
 804858a:       8b 1c 24                mov    (%esp),%ebx
 804858d:       c3                      ret
 804858e:       90                      nop
 804858f:       90                      nop
 8048590:       55                      push   %ebp
 8048591:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048593:       53                      push   %ebx
 8048594:       83 ec 04                sub    $0x4,%esp
 8048597:       a1 d4 96 04 08          mov    0x80496d4,%eax
 804859c:       83 f8 ff                cmp    $0xffffffff,%eax
 804859f:       74 13                   je     80485b4 <tolower@plt+0x22c>
 80485a1:       bb d4 96 04 08          mov    $0x80496d4,%ebx
 80485a6:       66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 80485a8:       83 eb 04                sub    $0x4,%ebx
 80485ab:       ff d0                   call   *%eax
 80485ad:       8b 03                   mov    (%ebx),%eax
 80485af:       83 f8 ff                cmp    $0xffffffff,%eax
 80485b2:       75 f4                   jne    80485a8 <tolower@plt+0x220>
 80485b4:       83 c4 04                add    $0x4,%esp
 80485b7:       5b                      pop    %ebx
 80485b8:       5d                      pop    %ebp
 80485b9:       c3                      ret
 80485ba:       90                      nop
 80485bb:       90                      nop

Disassembly of section .fini:

080485bc <.fini>:
 80485bc:       55                      push   %ebp
 80485bd:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80485bf:       53                      push   %ebx
 80485c0:       83 ec 04                sub    $0x4,%esp
 80485c3:       e8 00 00 00 00          call   80485c8 <tolower@plt+0x240>
 80485c8:       5b                      pop    %ebx
 80485c9:       81 c3 ec 11 00 00       add    $0x11ec,%ebx
 80485cf:       e8 fc fd ff ff          call   80483d0 <tolower@plt+0x48>
 80485d4:       59                      pop    %ecx
 80485d5:       5b                      pop    %ebx
 80485d6:       c9                      leave
 80485d7:       c3                      ret
```

Comment: This is homework, right?  It's like a bomb lab but with a stripped binary.  I don't think anyone can answer this without doing a whole lot of work for you.  Although I might try setting a breakpoint at the call to `<getchar@plt>`, and see what it does with the user's input after breaking out of whatever the surrounding loop does.

Comment: What is a bomb lab?  I want to do the work myself, I just do not know where to begin.  I will try setting a breakpoint there.

Comment: I set a breakpoint there but gdb hits that breakpoint before the user has a chance to enter input.

Comment: Yeah, setting a breakpoint on an instruction means it triggers *before* the instruction runs.  Try using `until` a few times, to step out of the loop.  I haven't looked at the code to see how it decides when to stop calling getchar, but unless the password is a single character, it's definitely more than once.

Comment: I set a breakpoint at 0x80484BF which I think is where the program makes the final comparison after the user input and got the following as the value of $ebp: "\250\321\377\377\370\204\004\b\n"  There are nine backslashes and including enter, that would be ten characters which I think is the length of the password.  I don't know how the numbers translate into characters though.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You mean the bytes in memory, starting from EBP?  The buffer ends below EBP, because it's part of the function's stack frame.  `cmpl   $0xa,-0x10(%ebp)` appears to be checking for a `\n`, and that's at a fixed offset from EBP (which is maybe the end of the buffer).

Comment: Is there any cmp command that compares the user input with the set password?  I have not found any other string value that could be the ten character password.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127023/discussion-between-masonc15-and-peter-cordes).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was compiled with `-O0`, because it's highly redundant and keeps everything in memory.

You'd have an easier time with a disassembler that put labels on branch targets, so you could see when execution might reaches a block of code with a jump from somewhere else, as well as (or instead of) falling through from earlier instructions.  Agner Fog's `objconv` disassembler does this.

---

`8048490  jmp    80484b9 <tolower@plt+0x131>` is the last instruction of the getchar loop (which loops a fixed 10 times).

It's followed by a loop that loads characters one at a time from `-0x1b(%ebp,%eax,1)`, and does

```
# eax = tolower(str[i])
sub    $0x31,%eax    # subtract '1'
cmp    $0x4,%eax
ja     80484b5   # jump over an increment of a counter at -0x10(%ebp)
```

So `cmpl   $0xa,-0x10(%ebp)` isn't looking for a newline, it's checking a counter to see if all 10 characters were between ASCII `'1'` and `'5'`, I think.

Comment: I am very new to x86 and cannot figure out how to use the objconv disassembler after spending more than an hour trying.  I have a Windows machine so things that would be easy on a Linux machine are not on mine.  Do you think every character of the password will be inbetween 1 and 5?  How else can I approach this problem?

Comment: @masonc15: Agner Fog distributes [objconv.exe for Windows](http://www.agner.org/optimize/), as well as source you can compile for Linux.  You don't have to know asm to install/use it, only to read the output.

Comment: @masonc15: How else can you approach it?  Well, by following the second loop yourself to see what it does.  1-5 is my first guess based on a quick look at what appears to be a loop over the string.  It seems plausible, but I didn't check every instruction to make sure it's consistent with that.  Single-stepping the code in a debugger is really helpful to verify that you've correctly figured out what it will do (esp. with `layout reg` in gdb so you can watch reg values change).

Comment: Thanks for the help.  What register would the password be stored in?

Comment: Also, what architecture would this code be?  MIPS, PowerPC, base, ARM?

Comment: @masonc15: The code doesn't appear to be checking what you input against a stored password, it's just doing some operations on each character and making a decision at the end.  A 32b register obviously isn't big enough to hold a string, just a pointer to the string.  It's your homework, ask your professor if you need more help.

Comment: Also, what architecture would what be?  I only see x86 code in your question, and wasn't talking about using anything else.

Comment: After disassembling further, I have found a string at memory location 0x08048626 that is " Su<~wBJIkL".  This is the only string I have found stored that is significant although when I enter this as the password, it does not work.  Does the program modify this string in some way?  I feel like this has to be related to the password.